# Replace Spark array values with values from python dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, replace

I have a Spark dataframe column having array values:

```
| data | arraydata |
| ---- | ---------
| text | [0,1,2,3] |
| page | [0,1,4,3] |
```

I want to replace [0,1,2,3,4] with [negative,positive,name,sequel,odd]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapping = {0: "negative", 1: "positive", 2: "name", 3: "sequel", 4: "odd"}
mapping_column = map_from_entries(array(*[struct(lit(k), lit(v)) for k, v in mapping.items()]))

df = df.withColumn("mapping", mapping_column) \
       .withColumn("arraydatav2", expr(""" transform(arraydata, x -> element_at(mapping, x))""")) \
       .drop("mapping")
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of creating a map. I wanted to create a more streamlined code (requires Spark 3.1)

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('text', [0,1,2,3]),
     ('page', [0,1,4,3])],
    ['data', 'arraydata'])

mapping = {0: "negative", 1: "positive", 2: "name", 3: "sequel", 4: "odd"}
```

Script:

```py
map_col = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for i in mapping.items() for x in i])
df = df.withColumn('arraydata', F.transform('arraydata', lambda x: map_col[x]))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +----+----------------------------------+
# |data|arraydata                         |
# +----+----------------------------------+
# |text|[negative, positive, name, sequel]|
# |page|[negative, positive, odd, sequel] |
# +----+----------------------------------+
```